Sub Panel to a Shop
I am attempting to get power out to my new shop via a sub panel. The shop is approximately 200 feet from the entry point in my house. I have 2 breaker spaces available in my main panel. What do I need to buy in preparation for this task? What size wire? What size and type conduit to run wires underground? I only need 120v throughout my little shop. Just lights and approximately 10 outlets.

The first thing to do is to figure out the total power needs for your shop. This is officially called a Load Calculation. There is a complex way of doing this for an entire building. For a shop it may be reasonable to estimate based on planned equipment. In particular, you need to consider:

Lighting, small appliances, etc. - Typically 15A to 20A is sufficient.
HVAC - Air conditioner? Resistance heaters? Heat pump? Unless you live in a very moderate climate, you will probably need something. Even it is plug-in space heaters you need to factor this into the total as it can be significant.
Power Tools - "Shop" typically means woodworking, welding or other stuff that uses a lot of power. But it can also be a quiet room to work on stuff that needs hardly any power at all. But anything beyond a few hundred watts should be included, if applicable.
EV Charging - If the shop is actually a garage (often a converted garage is used as a shop) or near where you park, EV charging may be in your future and should be factored in.
Future use?
Continuous Use Derate - You need to add 25% to the usage for continuous loads. This does not apply to everything, but broadly speaking for a mixed load it is easiest (and gives a little extra room for expansion) to apply it to all. So if you come up with 40A total, 40A x 1.25 = 50A as a feeder size.

Once you figure it out, then you know how big a circuit you need, generally based on total Watts divided by 240V to get Amps, assuming the loads are either mostly 240V or can be reasonably balanced across the two hot legs of the panel.
You need to make sure that the existing panel and utility service has enough capacity. For example, if your existing panel is a 200A panel on 200A service and your existing panel has a Load Calculation of 150A then you have 50A to spare and you can send 50A to the shop.
And the last major factor is Voltage Drop. Using the 50A example, a ampacity chart shows that you can use 6 AWG aluminum (in almost all cases for long distances to a subpanel, aluminum is preferred because it is much cheaper than copper). You plug the load (e.g., 50A) and the wire size (e.g., 6 AWG) into a voltage drop calculator. Now here is where the usage matters a lot. 120V has a higher voltage drop than 240V. Based on the initial description, you plan on only 120V. You will likely still wire it up for 240V (because of the way the US system works) but for voltage drop, unless you have substantial 240V loads such as HVAC or EV charging, you use 120V for the calculation.

120V, 200 feet, 40A (because you do the voltage drop based on expected usage, not circuit size), 6 AWG aluminum = 9.54%. That's way too much.
120V, 200 feet, 40A, 2 AWG aluminum = 3.91%. That's generally pretty reasonable.

So with that example, I would recommend 2 AWG aluminum x 3 (hot/hot/neutral) + 6 AWG aluminum (because that's the minimum for up to 100A).
But your actual amounts will vary depending on the total expected usage.
Once you figure out the necessary wire size, you can figure out conduit. There are a number of different types with varying costs and burial depth requirements.
